# Image scraping +python+URL +dynamic xpath+src

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I want to scrape image tag .
In which it is attached with src
For green and red different .

I want to write a for loop.

Sample : if green button :
Exit from loop
Else
Goto red and click
on it
example :pattern
button  button  button  button  button  button  button  but

1. Product 1 ----> green    red    green    red    green    red    green    red
2. product 2-----> red      red    green    green  green    green    green
3. product 3----->green    green   green    green  green    red     green

Comment: Since you are trying to click elements, Selenium browser works. It has support to xpath too. Specify more details for more relevant answers

Comment: For Red Button and for Green Button :src in <img> tag is different.  can you suggest me how can i write code by taking "src" element .with the below code i can able to click on both red and green buttons pls check                     follow_loop = range(9, 17)
for x in follow_loop:
xpath = "/html/body/edge-app/div[2]/ui-view/edge-view page/edge view/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/edge-widget-container/div/div[2]/div/div/edge-table-widget/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div["
xpath += str(x)
xpath += "]/div/img"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

Comment: I would be much help to answer your question if you can post HTML tag of both red and green buttons.

Comment: For green :<img class ="center-block" src="image/edgeCore-svg-shape-circle/x-0/y-0/w-16/h-16/border-09aa09/fill-09aa09/icon.png " style ="width:16px;height:16px"> ==$0                                 for red :<img class ="center-block" src="image/edgeCore-svg-shape-diamond/x-0/y-0/w-16/h-16/border-aa0909/fill-aa0909/icon.png " style ="width:16px;height:16px"> ==$0

Comment: please update the question to contain all the relevant information

Comment: updated the question. please check if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some Assumptions, I am providing python code, Still you have to modify according to your need although.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_chrome_driver")
driver.get(search_url)

imgTags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img")
totalResults = len(imgTags)

for img in imgTags:
    if img.get_attribute('src') == 'src_attribute_of_red':
        img.click()
    elif img.get_attribute('src') == 'src_attribute_of_green':
        break
```

Comment: this code is not working for me .i have updated the question please check and help me

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me, Could you post the exact website So, It would be easier?

Comment: sorry ,  i can't post the website but i can tell you more clearly    
Pattern of website buttons 
product 1 : red      green  red     green   red 
product 2 : green  green  red      red      red
product 3 :green   red      green  red      red 
I can able to click on the products but i can't able to open the red buttons 
And one more "img.get_attribute('src') == 'src_attribute_of_red'"when i run this code getting false even for Green button also